# setState inside setInterval causing to hang the application | React Native

Tags: react-native, timer, state, setinterval, setstate

I am working to show the `Stopwatch` and the timer is running properly but when timer is running and i am putting the application on background and then when the app comes to foreground the UI is blocked and none of the click event working.

Here is my core code snippet :

```
this.interval = this.interval ? this.interval : setInterval(async () => {
      this.setState((state, props) => ({ elapsed: new Date() - state.startTime - state.pausedTime }))
    }, 1)
```

Please do let me know in case of i am missing anything.

Suggestions appreciated
Thanks

Answer (score 2):

You should get familiar with: https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/timers

And especially: `InteractionManager.requestAnimationFrame(<function>)`. This would give you a proper approach for not hanging the UI thread, e.g.

```
InteractionManager.requestAnimationFrame(function() {
  this.setState({ elapsed: new Date(), ...}));
  ...
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I've made a mistake by passing interval as `1` but it should be `1000` ms.
Thanks all.